# MSBuild copying a DLL from a project directory which is set to Do Not Copy

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a `C#` project which has a directory that is just for carrying some DLLs not meant to be copied into the project's `OutputPath` when the project is built.

The DLLs are added to the `csproj` and reside inside a folder in the project. The `Build Action` is set to None and `Copy to Output Dir` is set to `Do not copy`.

When I build my project, I see the DLL appearing in my output directory which is `bin/Debug`

Here is what I have tried

1. I tried to set the Build Action to `Content`. Still copies.
2. I deleted the DLLs, just to make sure they aren't coming from elsewhere, they do not get copied. So the source is that one directory in project.

I am using `VS2019` to build, what am I missing?

Comment: See which step copied the files, https://msbuildlog.com/ and then you can suppress that.

Comment: Could you please share the csproj file of the dll with us?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT The dll file that is being copied over is Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll

Comment: @fahadash,did you install `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel` nuget package and did the project reference another project? And did you try to create a new same project and set the same targetframework version, the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

**1)** first, delete the dlls and the folder of the Dlls, also make sure that you have not installed any related nuget packages and referenced any related projects.

**2)** close VS ,delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**3)** restart VS and your project, then readd the dlls and try again.

If the issue still persists, please try to create a new project to test it or share a small sample with us to troubleshoot the issue.